# converting a string into a double

Tags: c, double

I am looking for a way to get floating point input from a user.

My way of going about this is to use a self-made getstrn function and plug that into another function which would convert the string into a double.

My safe get string:

```
void safeGetString(char arr[], int limit){
    int c, i;
    i = 0;
    c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n'){
        if (i < limit -1){
            arr[i] = c;
            i++;
        }
        c = getchar();
    }
    arr[i] = '\0';
}
```

What would be the best way to write this get_double function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the strtod function:

```
char *end;
double num = strtod(arr, &end);
```

The end will point after the last char that was processed. You can set the second to `NULL` if you don't care about that. Or you can use `atof`: `atof(str)` is equivalent to `strtod(str, (char **)NULL)`.

But you should care, since you can check if the input is malformed:

```
if (*end != '\0')
  // Handle malformed input
```

Comment: But if you don't care about the end, then you can't tell the difference between malformed input and 0, and out-of-range values result in undefined behavior for `atof`.

Comment: @Steve: If you want to tell the difference between malformed input and 0, then by definition you care about the end pointer.

Comment: @Stephen: that's what I said. They call it the "contrapositive" ;-)

Comment: @Terminus: the check for malformed input should be `(end == arr)`.

Comment: @Stephen: Won't that still accept inputs like `0.1a` where `end` will be `arr + 3`?

Comment: @terminus: if you want to get really pernickity, you should do the check you already have, *and* check somewhere that `*arr != 0`. Unless there's a reason to treat an empty string as 0, which sometimes there is.

Comment: @Terminus: Right.  I suppose it depends on what you consider "malformed".  In my usage of `strtod`, I'm usually parsing a double and then doing something else with the remainder of the string, so `0.1a` isn't malformed.  Other usage may differ.

Answer (score 4):

Use `strtod`, that's what it's for. And `fgets` can replace your `safeGetString` function.

Answer (score 4):

Any of:

- [strtod()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtod/)
- [atof()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atof/)
- [sscanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/)

Of these sscanf offers the strongest validation, since the other two return a valid double value of 0.0 if the input cannot be interpreted as a double, while sscanf() returns the number of format specifiers successfully matched to the input. So:

```
input_valid = (sscanf( arr, "%lf", value ) != 0 ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Why are you not using `fgets()`?
2. You're looking for `atof()`.

*(Thanks to R. for fixing my idiotic suggestion in part 1)*

Comment: (1) `gets` is unsafe, it overruns buffers because there's no way to stop it reading other than for the user to enter a newline character before your buffer is full. `fgets` is OK.

Comment: Regarding 1. I think the question makes it clear that a safe function is intended. "gets does not let you specify a limit on how many characters are to be read, so you must be careful with the size of the array pointed by str to avoid buffer overflows"

Comment: Good point. And I'm usually the one whining about functions like strcpy and strcat.

Comment: You can stop with the downvoting already, the answer has been edited.