# optimal way to convert string to double?

Tags: c++, string, double

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [converting a string into a double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308536/converting-a-string-into-a-double)

What is the optimal way to convert string to double ?
am using sstream but I feel it is not that fast.. is there a faster wawy without using any external libraries or sth.

Comment: "I feel that it is not fast" - how fast is it, and how fast do you need it to be?

Comment: Is there a pattern to these strings that will be converted to doubles?  If so, the best way may be to hand roll your own function.

Comment: Have you tried `strtod`?

Comment: Please see the similar Q/A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392981/how-can-i-convert-string-to-double-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtod()` will have less overhead than using `sstream`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char * s = ...;
double d = strtod(s, 0);
```

Comment: Of course, if his input is in a `string`, he'll have to use `c_str()` to get it.  And it needs some error checking.

Answer (score 0):

you can use boost library lexical cast
They also include performance test results on their documentation page
[boost lexical cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)

cheers

Comment: @Mike: Early versions did, newer versions have overrides for a number of types, including double.  It only falls back to using the stringstream if it doesn't have its own mechanism for performing the conversion.

Comment: @Mike, thats right, in their test results they are comparing their method to sstream and showing that lexicalcast is f#aster